# XMLAdapter for HashMap

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I want to convert a list of items inside of my payaload and convert them into a hashmap. Basically, what I have is an Item xml representation which have a list of ItemID. Each ItemID has an idType in it. However, inside my Item class, i want these ItemIDs to be represented as a Map.

```
HashMap<ItemIDType, ItemID>
```

The incoming payload will represent this as a list

```
<Item>...
    <ItemIDs>
       <ItemID type="external" id="XYZ"/>
       <ItemID type="internal" id="20011"/>
    </ItemIDs>
</Item>
```

but I want an adapter that will convert this into a HashMap

```
"external" => "xyz"
"internal" => "20011"
```

I am right now using a LinkedList

```
public class MapHashMapListAdapter extends XmlAdapter<LinkedList<ItemID>, Map<ItemIDType, ItemID>> {

     public LinkedList<ItemID> marshal(final Map<ItemIDType, ItemID> v) throws Exception { ... }

     public Map<ItemIDType, ItemID> unmarshal(final LinkedList<ItemID> v) throws Exception { ... }

}
```

but for some reason when my payload gets converted, it fails to convert the list into a hashmap. The incoming LinkedList of the method unmarshal is an empty list. Do you guys have any idea what I am doing wrong here? Do I need to create my own data type here to handle the LinkedList?

Comment: What means *fails to convert*? Do you get some error message, or does something happen what you don't expect?
And likely the error is in the code you didn't show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of converting the `Map` to a `LinkedList` you need to convert it to a domain object.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public final class MyMapAdapter extends

   XmlAdapter<MyMapType,Map<Integer, String>> {

   @Override
   public MyMapType marshal(Map<Integer, String> arg0) throws Exception {
      MyMapType myMapType = new MyMapType();
      for(Entry<Integer, String> entry : arg0.entrySet()) {
         MyMapEntryType myMapEntryType =
            new MyMapEntryType();
         myMapEntryType.key = entry.getKey();
         myMapEntryType.value = entry.getValue();
         myMapType.entry.add(myMapEntryType);
      }
      return myMapType;
   }

   @Override
   public Map<Integer, String> unmarshal(MyMapType arg0) throws Exception {
      HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
      for(MyMapEntryType myEntryType : arg0.entry) {
         hashMap.put(myEntryType.key, myEntryType.value);
      }
      return hashMap;
   }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

Comment: I ended up creating my own data type as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to official oracle documentation over here :
[XmlAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html). They have given a similar example for HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my old universal solution, **but never do this in real project**, it is not cross-language (it's only for java client + java server solution). SerializableAdapler.java can marshal and unmarshal any java Object. For marshaling it serializes java object to String, then encodes it to base64. For unmarshaling it decodes base64 string and deserialize it for getting java object. Btw, in this solution you need helpers (SerializableAdapler.java, Base64Coder.java) on both server and client sides. In normal solution you need only one interface like SomeService.java on client side (and both SomeService.java and SomeServiceImpl.java on server side). I tested it with http://cxf.apache.org/docs/a-simple-jax-ws-service.html , but you can use other webservices framework.

SomeService.java

```
package some.services.interfaces;

import some.services.interfaces.helpers.SerializableAdapler;

import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@WebService
public interface SomeService {
    String sayHi(@WebParam(name = "text") String text);

    String sayHiToUser(@WebParam(name = "user") String user);

    /* Advanced usecase of passing an Interface in.  JAX-WS/JAXB does not
     * support interfaces directly.  Special XmlAdapter classes need to
     * be written to handle them
     */
    boolean add(@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(SerializableAdapler.class) @WebParam(name = "data") Map<String, String> data);

    boolean addAll(@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(SerializableAdapler.class) @WebParam(name = "columns") List<String> columns, @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(SerializableAdapler.class) @WebParam(name = "datas") List<List<String>> datas);

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(SerializableAdapler.class)
    List<String> showColumns();

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(SerializableAdapler.class)
    List<List<String>> getDatas();
}
```

SerializableAdapler.java

```
package some.services.interfaces.helpers;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import java.io.*;

public class SerializableAdapler<BoundType> extends XmlAdapter<String,BoundType> {
    @Override
    public BoundType unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        byte [] data = Base64Coder.decode( v );
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(  data ) );

        BoundType o  = (BoundType)ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        return o;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(BoundType v) throws Exception {
        if (v instanceof Serializable) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(v);
            oos.close();
            return new String(Base64Coder.encode(baos.toByteArray()));
        } else {
            throw new Exception("BoundType v is not serializable: "+v.getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

Base64Coder.java

```
package some.services.interfaces.helpers;

// Copyright 2003-2010 Christian d'Heureuse, Inventec Informatik AG, Zurich, Switzerland
// www.source-code.biz, www.inventec.ch/chdh
//
// This module is multi-licensed and may be used under the terms
// of any of the following licenses:
//
//  EPL, Eclipse Public License, V1.0 or later, http://www.eclipse.org/legal
//  LGPL, GNU Lesser General Public License, V2.1 or later, http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html
//  GPL, GNU General Public License, V2 or later, http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
//  AGPL, GNU Affero General Public License V3 or later, http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl.html
//  AL, Apache License, V2.0 or later, http://www.apache.org/licenses
//  BSD, BSD License, http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php
//  MIT, MIT License, http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
//
// Please contact the author if you need another license.
// This module is provided "as is", without warranties of any kind.
//
// Project home page: www.source-code.biz/base64coder/java

/**
 * A Base64 encoder/decoder.
 *
 * <p>
 * This class is used to encode and decode data in Base64 format as described in RFC 1521.
 *
 * @author
 *    Christian d'Heureuse, Inventec Informatik AG, Zurich, Switzerland, www.source-code.biz
 */
public class Base64Coder {

    // The line separator string of the operating system.
    private static final String systemLineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    // Mapping table from 6-bit nibbles to Base64 characters.
    private static final char[] map1 = new char[64];
    static {
        int i=0;
        for (char c='A'; c<='Z'; c++) map1[i++] = c;
        for (char c='a'; c<='z'; c++) map1[i++] = c;
        for (char c='0'; c<='9'; c++) map1[i++] = c;
        map1[i++] = '+'; map1[i++] = '/'; }

    // Mapping table from Base64 characters to 6-bit nibbles.
    private static final byte[] map2 = new byte[128];
    static {
        for (int i=0; i<map2.length; i++) map2[i] = -1;
        for (int i=0; i<64; i++) map2[map1[i]] = (byte)i; }

    /**
     * Encodes a string into Base64 format.
     * No blanks or line breaks are inserted.
     * @param s  A String to be encoded.
     * @return   A String containing the Base64 encoded data.
     */
    public static String encodeString (String s) {
        return new String(encode(s.getBytes())); }

    /**
     * Encodes a byte array into Base 64 format and breaks the output into lines of 76 characters.
     * This method is compatible with <code>sun.misc.BASE64Encoder.encodeBuffer(byte[])</code>.
     * @param in  An array containing the data bytes to be encoded.
     * @return    A String containing the Base64 encoded data, broken into lines.
     */
    public static String encodeLines (byte[] in) {
        return encodeLines(in, 0, in.length, 76, systemLineSeparator); }

    /**
     * Encodes a byte array into Base 64 format and breaks the output into lines.
     * @param in            An array containing the data bytes to be encoded.
     * @param iOff          Offset of the first byte in <code>in</code> to be processed.
     * @param iLen          Number of bytes to be processed in <code>in</code>, starting at <code>iOff</code>.
     * @param lineLen       Line length for the output data. Should be a multiple of 4.
     * @param lineSeparator The line separator to be used to separate the output lines.
     * @return              A String containing the Base64 encoded data, broken into lines.
     */
    public static String encodeLines (byte[] in, int iOff, int iLen, int lineLen, String lineSeparator) {
        int blockLen = (lineLen*3) / 4;
        if (blockLen <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        int lines = (iLen+blockLen-1) / blockLen;
        int bufLen = ((iLen+2)/3)*4 + lines*lineSeparator.length();
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(bufLen);
        int ip = 0;
        while (ip < iLen) {
            int l = Math.min(iLen-ip, blockLen);
            buf.append(encode(in, iOff+ip, l));
            buf.append(lineSeparator);
            ip += l; }
        return buf.toString(); }

    /**
     * Encodes a byte array into Base64 format.
     * No blanks or line breaks are inserted in the output.
     * @param in  An array containing the data bytes to be encoded.
     * @return    A character array containing the Base64 encoded data.
     */
    public static char[] encode (byte[] in) {
        return encode(in, 0, in.length); }

    /**
     * Encodes a byte array into Base64 format.
     * No blanks or line breaks are inserted in the output.
     * @param in    An array containing the data bytes to be encoded.
     * @param iLen  Number of bytes to process in <code>in</code>.
     * @return      A character array containing the Base64 encoded data.
     */
    public static char[] encode (byte[] in, int iLen) {
        return encode(in, 0, iLen); }

    /**
     * Encodes a byte array into Base64 format.
     * No blanks or line breaks are inserted in the output.
     * @param in    An array containing the data bytes to be encoded.
     * @param iOff  Offset of the first byte in <code>in</code> to be processed.
     * @param iLen  Number of bytes to process in <code>in</code>, starting at <code>iOff</code>.
     * @return      A character array containing the Base64 encoded data.
     */
    public static char[] encode (byte[] in, int iOff, int iLen) {
        int oDataLen = (iLen*4+2)/3;       // output length without padding
        int oLen = ((iLen+2)/3)*4;         // output length including padding
        char[] out = new char[oLen];
        int ip = iOff;
        int iEnd = iOff + iLen;
        int op = 0;
        while (ip < iEnd) {
            int i0 = in[ip++] & 0xff;
            int i1 = ip < iEnd ? in[ip++] & 0xff : 0;
            int i2 = ip < iEnd ? in[ip++] & 0xff : 0;
            int o0 = i0 >>> 2;
            int o1 = ((i0 &   3) << 4) | (i1 >>> 4);
            int o2 = ((i1 & 0xf) << 2) | (i2 >>> 6);
            int o3 = i2 & 0x3F;
            out[op++] = map1[o0];
            out[op++] = map1[o1];
            out[op] = op < oDataLen ? map1[o2] : '='; op++;
            out[op] = op < oDataLen ? map1[o3] : '='; op++; }
        return out; }

    /**
     * Decodes a string from Base64 format.
     * No blanks or line breaks are allowed within the Base64 encoded input data.
     * @param s  A Base64 String to be decoded.
     * @return   A String containing the decoded data.
     * @throws   IllegalArgumentException If the input is not valid Base64 encoded data.
     */
    public static String decodeString (String s) {
        return new String(decode(s)); }

    /**
     * Decodes a byte array from Base64 format and ignores line separators, tabs and blanks.
     * CR, LF, Tab and Space characters are ignored in the input data.
     * This method is compatible with <code>sun.misc.BASE64Decoder.decodeBuffer(String)</code>.
     * @param s  A Base64 String to be decoded.
     * @return   An array containing the decoded data bytes.
     * @throws   IllegalArgumentException If the input is not valid Base64 encoded data.
     */
    public static byte[] decodeLines (String s) {
        char[] buf = new char[s.length()];
        int p = 0;
        for (int ip = 0; ip < s.length(); ip++) {
            char c = s.charAt(ip);
            if (c != ' ' && c != '\r' && c != '\n' && c != '\t')
                buf[p++] = c; }
        return decode(buf, 0, p); }

    /**
     * Decodes a byte array from Base64 format.
     * No blanks or line breaks are allowed within the Base64 encoded input data.
     * @param s  A Base64 String to be decoded.
     * @return   An array containing the decoded data bytes.
     * @throws   IllegalArgumentException If the input is not valid Base64 encoded data.
     */
    public static byte[] decode (String s) {
        return decode(s.toCharArray()); }

    /**
     * Decodes a byte array from Base64 format.
     * No blanks or line breaks are allowed within the Base64 encoded input data.
     * @param in  A character array containing the Base64 encoded data.
     * @return    An array containing the decoded data bytes.
     * @throws    IllegalArgumentException If the input is not valid Base64 encoded data.
     */
    public static byte[] decode (char[] in) {
        return decode(in, 0, in.length); }

    /**
     * Decodes a byte array from Base64 format.
     * No blanks or line breaks are allowed within the Base64 encoded input data.
     * @param in    A character array containing the Base64 encoded data.
     * @param iOff  Offset of the first character in <code>in</code> to be processed.
     * @param iLen  Number of characters to process in <code>in</code>, starting at <code>iOff</code>.
     * @return      An array containing the decoded data bytes.
     * @throws      IllegalArgumentException If the input is not valid Base64 encoded data.
     */
    public static byte[] decode (char[] in, int iOff, int iLen) {
        if (iLen%4 != 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Length of Base64 encoded input string is not a multiple of 4.");
        while (iLen > 0 && in[iOff+iLen-1] == '=') iLen--;
        int oLen = (iLen*3) / 4;
        byte[] out = new byte[oLen];
        int ip = iOff;
        int iEnd = iOff + iLen;
        int op = 0;
        while (ip < iEnd) {
            int i0 = in[ip++];
            int i1 = in[ip++];
            int i2 = ip < iEnd ? in[ip++] : 'A';
            int i3 = ip < iEnd ? in[ip++] : 'A';
            if (i0 > 127 || i1 > 127 || i2 > 127 || i3 > 127)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal character in Base64 encoded data.");
            int b0 = map2[i0];
            int b1 = map2[i1];
            int b2 = map2[i2];
            int b3 = map2[i3];
            if (b0 < 0 || b1 < 0 || b2 < 0 || b3 < 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal character in Base64 encoded data.");
            int o0 = ( b0       <<2) | (b1>>>4);
            int o1 = ((b1 & 0xf)<<4) | (b2>>>2);
            int o2 = ((b2 &   3)<<6) |  b3;
            out[op++] = (byte)o0;
            if (op<oLen) out[op++] = (byte)o1;
            if (op<oLen) out[op++] = (byte)o2; }
        return out; }

    // Dummy constructor.
    private Base64Coder() {}

} // end class Base64Coder
```

SomeServiceImpl.java

```
package some.services.implement;

import some.services.interfaces.SomeService;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import java.util.*;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "some.services.interfaces.SomeService",
        serviceName = "SomeService")
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeSerive {
    public String sayHi(String text) {
        return "Hi, "+text;
    }

    public String sayHiToUser(String user) {
        return "Hello, "+user;
    }

    protected List<String> columns = null;
    protected final List<List<String>> datas = new LinkedList<List<String>>();

    public boolean add(Map<String, String> data) {
        ...
    }

    public boolean addAll(List<String> columns, List<List<String>> datas) {
        ...
    }

    public List<String> showColumns() {
        ...
    }

    public List<List<String>> getDatas() {
        ...
    }
}
```

P.S.: This solution example is for Java 7 (without normal base64 support). Please do not edit for later Java versions.