# how to marshall/unmarshall Map using jaxb?

Tags: java, jaxb

f.e. I have an xml:

```
<a>
  <b id="1">abc</b>
  <b id="22">bzzz</b>
</a>
```

I want to map it onto
     Map < Integer, String >

is it possible with jaxb? If yes - how?

Thank you.

Comment: This question was asked so many times: [Is it possible to use JAXB to map from schema to a java.util.Map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881712), [XMLAdapter for HashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975068), [Problems marshalling a map in Jaxb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793283), [Custom Map<Object,Object> XmlAdapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034781).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read documentation for [XmlAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html). It gives you what you want.

Comment: +1 - Here is another link you may find useful:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

Comment: An operational example for generics is also available here (personal blog post): http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.nl/2012/08/jaxb-annotation-summary-advanced-topics_9.html