# using HashMap in XSD

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

Our applications uses java classes generated from [XML Schema Definition (XSD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema). I need to use HashMap for storing key, value pairs.

The Result class should be something like this from xsd

```
public class Employee{
    private String name;
    private Map<String, Object> dataMap;
}
```

Tried schemagen, jaxbcontext etc, but still unable to do it successfully . Tried below in XSD but getting "List" in the generated java class (instead of map). Using JDK 1.8

```
<xs:complexType name="employee">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="dataMap">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="key" minOccurs="0" type="xs:string"/>
                  <xs:element name="value" minOccurs="0" type="xs:anyType"/>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Appreciate any help/suggestions

Comment: I think you should look at `XmlAdapter` usage. See linked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975068/xmladapter-for-hashmap)

Comment: I was able to achieve it using jaxb:bindings (<jaxb:baseType name="java.util.Map&lt;String,Object&gt;" />) and can/will post full solution shortly. Meanwhile I wish with solution  if I can somehow initialize the HashMap as empty when class is generated using xsd (currently the getter returns null)

Comment: Like the list is initialized with new list when getter is called for the first time ?

Comment: yes, but trying to do this with Map as well

Comment: If you dont find a solution, please create issue here https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools We could work on new xjc plugin for that kind of field initialization